# Eigenstates of a spin 1 object

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space

Since the eigenvalues of $S_z$ are -1, 0, 1, is it correct to say that the eigenvectors are

$$\begin{bmatrix} 1\\0\\0\end{bmatrix},\begin{bmatrix} 0\\0\\0\end{bmatrix}, \textrm{and} \, \begin{bmatrix} 0\\0\\-1\end{bmatrix}$$

Comment: An eigenvector couldn't be zero by its definition.

Answer (score 3):

The answer is no. The correct normalized eigenvectors can be casted in the form

$$\begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \\ 0\end{pmatrix},\begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ 1 \\ 0\end{pmatrix},\begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ 0 \\ 1\end{pmatrix}.$$

In this basis, the operator $S_z$ is diagonal with the eigenvalues on the diagonal

$$\begin{pmatrix} 1 &0 &0 \\ 0&0&0 \\ 0&0&-1\end{pmatrix}.$$

This is the usual result of the process of diagonalization of the matrix.